# Trying to integrate facebook with libgdx, where to implement this code because there is no "module:app" is present?

Tags: libgdx, android-studio-2.3

According to facebook:-

"Add the following to the `dependencies {}` section of your `build.gradle` (module: app) file to compile the latest version of the Facebook SDK:

`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'`"

I don't see any module named app in the android studio project.where to add above line?

Comment: It would be nice if you specified which specific project you have in mind

Comment: It's a libgdx game.

Answer (score 0):

`module:app` in this case just means the main android app. So you should add the dependency to the android module.

Then I bet your next question how to use this library from the core since the Android module depends on the core module and not vice versa so you do not have access to the library in the core project. One way is to pass a contract to the platform launchers where each implements it differently.

```
//Simple contract
public interface IPlatformContract {
    void runThis();
}

// Core project (MyGame)
private IPlatformContract platformContract;
public MyGame(IPlatformContract platformContract) {
    this.platformContract = platformContract;
}

//DesktopLauncher
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

    // Launch desktop with it's own implementation of the contract.
    new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(new IPlatformContract() {
        @Override
        public void runThis() {
            System.out.println(" I run on desktop!");
        }
    }), config);
}

//AndroidLauncher, different way. Here the class itself implements the contract.
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements IPlatformContract{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new LibgdxTestEnvironment(this), config);
    }

    @Override
    public void runThis() {
        System.out.println("I run on android!");
    }
}
```

You can pass along the contract to other classes like screens in your core project so you have access to it. You can even make a Singleton.

Comment: @MadmenyoThere's no dependency section in module:android

Comment: You can just add it on the main (project level) `build.gradle` inside the dependancies of `project(":android")`. You could also add it to the project level `build.gradle` and Gradle even recommends to do that but since LibGDX does it all from the project level `build.gradle` there is no reason to do it differently.